# where can i find opencv libraries directory on mac os?

Tags: opencv

I want to include opencv libraries in a make file.What is the directory to include?
I had tried using

> \opt\local\include

but i could not run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

> /usr/local/include/

It will work

Comment: @KoteswaraRaoGani in SO we say _thanks_ by upvoting. If this answers your question, please mark as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

All the opencv libraries can be found using the command:
cd /usr/local/include/